# Как задать кодировку в сервлете?

Tags: кодировка, servlet

Я использую `JSP` для отображения информации для пользователя, и если я не задаю кодировку, то вместо русских символов получаю иероглифы. Я не использую фрэймворков типа `Spring` только нативное `Servlet API`.

Я исправляю это так : `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");`, но мне это не нравиться, выглядит как костыль в каждом сервлете это писать.

Есть способ сделать это один раз и на всегда? Может где-то есть файл с настройками или еще что-то? Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: можно использовать java filter как [тут](https://dertompson.com/2007/01/29/encoding-filter-for-java-web-applications/) , такой вариант устроит?

Comment: @MrFylypenko то что надо! Спасибо.

Comment: Почему не задаешь в JSP?

Comment: @Alex78191 задаю этого не достаточно